# Installing IBM JDK and JRE

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-jdk

All, I am trying to install the IBM JDK and JRE in the SLED 11 SP3. So far, I just found the packages address in the IBM website. But I have confuse with these links. Becasue Both of the JDK and JRE have two links leading to download. Could anyone please tell me what is the difference between them? Thanks.

**Updated**

If the application I developed is deployed to IBM Websphere 8.x. Which JDK should I install? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you've shown looks to be the "Developer Kits" provided through IBM developerWorks for development use.

For IBM Java SDKs that work with WebSphere Application Server, you would obtain them as part of your WebSphere Application Server packages.

Here is links to the download documents:

- [WAS v8.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021159)
- [WAS v8.5.5](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038625)

You can find the parts that you need and follow the instructions to download them from Passport Advantage Online.

Note that Java SDK v6 comes embedded with WAS v8.0 and v8.5.5. So there is not a separate install for it -- You get it when you have WAS (classic) installed.  WAS v8.5.5 comes with other choices for Java SDK that you can optionally install e.g. Java SDK v7.

More information is available in WAS Knowledge Center:

- [WAS v8.0](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-dist&topic=welcome_installing)
- [WAS v8.5.5](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-dist&topic=cins_dldocs)

Answer (score 1):

I will explain here what have I done to install Websphere Application Server V8.5 on my RedHat OS.

Download this:

```
WAS_ND_V8.5.5_1_OF_3
WAS_ND_V8.5.5_2_OF_3
WAS_ND_V8.5.5_3_OF_3
WAS_V8.5.5_SUPPL_1_OF_3
WAS_V8.5.5_SUPPL_2_OF_3
WAS_V8.5.5_SUPPL_3_OF_3
WS_SDK_JAVA_TEV7.0_1OF3_WAS_8.5.5
WS_SDK_JAVA_TEV7.0_2OF3_WAS_8.5.5
WS_SDK_JAVA_TEV7.0_3OF3_WAS_8.5.5
java full version "JRE 1.6.0 IBM Linux build pxa6460_26sr7fp1ifx-20140220_01 (SR7 FP1)"
```

I think that is all you need. Install in this order:

- java JRE
- SDK_Java
- WAS_ND
- WAS SUPPL

If you have any problems please leva a comment.